# Xamarin.iOS binding: Missing first argument in Event args

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I was trying to create an Xamarin.iOS binding for an existing iOS SDK. I used ObjectiveC-Sharpie to create ApiDefinition.cs and used it in Xamarin binding project to create dll file. The library worked as expected and I was able to test the dll with a sample app.

As next step, I was trying to change Objective-C Delegates into C# Events. I followed the Xamarin documentation and other available projects of similar nature. However, the generated events has first argument from the original method missing all the time.

The original Objective-C protocol method was:

```
- (void)foundDevice:(Device*)device amongstAvailableDevices:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
```

Here is what I did:

1. This is how ApiDefinition.cs looks like:

   ```
   [BaseType (typeof (NSObject), Name="MyClass", Delegates=new string [] {"Delegate"}, Events = new Type [] { typeof (MyClassDelegate) })]
   interface MyClass
   {
       [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Weak)]
       [NullAllowed]
       NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

       [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
       MyClassDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

       [Static, Export ("sharedInstance")]
       MyClass SharedInstance();
   }


   [Protocol,Model]
   [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
   interface MyClassDelegate
   {
      ...
      [Export ("foundDevice:amongstAvailableDevices:"), EventArgs("MyClassFoundDevice")]
       void FoundDevice(Device device, NSDictionary deviceDictionary);
      ...
   }
   ```
2. The project complied and I imported the dll file in the Sample project. The Events for the above delegate were being generated fine:

   ```
   MyClass finder = new MyClass();
   finder.FoundDevice += (object sender, MyClassFoundDeviceEventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("Found device " + e.DeviceDictionary.ToString());
   };
   ```

However, I was unable to access the first argument of the delegate method (Device device in this case). As in, if I try accessing e.device, it is giving compile error - not even showing up in auto-complete suggestion. This happened for all the delegate methods: first argument was not accessible from the eventArgs. MyClassFoundDeviceEventArgs class looks like:

```
 public class MyClassFoundDeviceEventArgs : EventArgs
 {
        //
        // Properties
        //
        public NSDictionary DeviceDictionary {
            [CompilerGenerated]
            get;
            [CompilerGenerated]
            set;
        }

        //
        // Constructors
        //
        public MyClassFoundDeviceEventArgs (NSDictionary deviceDictionary);
  }
```

I tried adding a dummy first argument to the managed method declaration in ApiDefinition:

```
void FoundDevice(MyClass this, Device device, NSDictionary deviceDictionary);
```

I was able to access "Device device" from eventargs but the project failed to compile, giving an error:

Error MT4117: The registrar found a signature mismatch in the method - the selector foundDevice:amongstAvailableDevices: indicates the method takes 2 parameters, while the managed method FoundDevice has 3 parameters. (MT4117).

Comment: Isn't the sender the device?

Comment: @SKall Since it is a binding project from an iOS SDK, not all the delegate methods have their first argument as sender. e.g. there are a couple of method with first argument as deviceProperty which gets lost on creating the C# binding. If the original SDK was such that all methods had first argument as sender - it might work.

Comment: You checked that the runtime object 'sender' then is't the device? Can you post the ObjC header file or at least the portion related to the event?

Comment: @SKall Please see the edited post above for the original method name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding method with no parameters in Xamarin iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026289/binding-method-with-no-parameters-in-xamarin-ios)